# What are some exercises, according to Catholicism, to keep a mindfulness on Christ?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism, spirituality

So throught my life my relationship with christ was very "secular", although I believed in the religion only on sundays or on rare ocasions would I remember of christ.

But this has changed, due to various mistakes I've made. Certain experiences and other ideas made me consider following christ in a more religious and spiritual way the thing is my life right now although its certainly not bad, i can't stop looking at the past and seeing doom and sometimes it goes so bad to self pity.

And I would like to in this moments just remind myself of christ because when I do I think more rationally and stop "feeling" the doom and gloom in the future

A friend of mine has recomended me the works of the CEO of jesuits well, maybe the COO considering that jesus runs the whole thing... But I can't read a book because of my conditions which make reading a book thats longer than 50-100 page's nearly impossible unless I go to the library and even then its hard.

So any idea's on how I can focus myself on christ and reassure that he really is sleeping next to the wheel of the boat, or on what my friend is recomending?

Answer (score 1):

**What are some exercises, according to Catholicism, to keep a mindfulness on Christ?**

This is truly a great question, as it deals with improving one’s closeness to Jesus who is called the Christ.

Some ***exercises*** to help keep us mindful on Christ could be as follows (no particular order is intended):

- Have a spiritual director whom you feel comfortable and confident with to talk things over with. The more traditional priests would be of great value here.
- Prayer is an obvious point. Perhaps try saying the rosary every day or the Way of the Cross weekly or perhaps monthly.
- Take a yearly spiritual retreat and/or parish mission. Oh yes, leave the cell phone at home!
- Practical ways are not to be overlooked either. Every time one hears the *Sacred Name of Jesus*, one could try making a habit of making an inclination of one’s head in honour of Our Lord. This could be extended to the *Holy Name of Mary*, the saint of the day and the patron saint of the location one is in at particular moment. (This is something I have been doing for decades now, and it really keeps my mind alert, especially during homilies at mass.)
- Make periodic pilgrimages. Local ones are fine. If you do not have any in your area, make one. My parish church is named in honour of St. James the Greater. Sure I drive to church on Sundays as my wife has leg problems. But that does not stop me from walking occasionally to Mass through the woods with my pilgrim staff, just as if I were doing the [**Camino de Santiago**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camino_de_Santiago)! An hour and a half walk each way.
- Try reading a little of some tradition books on Catholic spirituality each day, such as [***The Imitation of Christ***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Imitation_of_Christ).

Answer (score 1):

E.F. Schumacher, who was a Jewish convert to Catholicism turned me on to the [Jesus Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Prayer), which he used as a sort of thought experiment as to how one could pray always like St. Paul enjoins.

The Jesus Prayer

> Jesus Christ Son of the Living God have mercy on me a sinner.

is a prayer that can be repeated practically between thoughts.  It, like the Hail Mary, is rooted in scripture and is a good way to keep Jesus in your mind all the time.  The prayer itself, is definitely more of an Eastern Orthodox tradition, but it is perfectly appropriate for Catholics:

The Catechism of the Catholic Church says:

> This prayer is possible "at all times" because it is not one occupation among others but the only occupation: that of loving God, which animates and transfigures every action in Christ Jesus

> [CCC 2668](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P9F.HTM)

Comment: Good point made in your post!